# Execute function inside function template only for those types that have the function defined

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

I have a function template which takes many different types as it's input.  Out of those types only one of them has a `getInt()` function. Hence I want the code to run the function only for that type. Please suggest a solution. Thanks

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

class X {
    public:
    int getInt(){
        return 9;
    }
};

class Y{

};

template<typename T>
void f(T& v){
    // error: 'class Y' has no member named 'getInt'
    // also tried std::is_same<T, X>::value 
    if(typeid(T).name() == typeid(X).name()){
        int i = v.getInt();// I want this to be called for X only
    }
}

int main(){
    Y y;
    f(y);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `type_info` structure have a [equality comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp), so `typeid(T) == typeid(X)` should work as well.

Comment: Use: `if constexpr` with condition `is_same_v<T,X>`.

Comment: The solution to this will officially become more elegant later this year with Concepts. Not super helpful right now, I know.

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem. A couple mentioned above. You could also use *traits* of different variants to see if a type have a callable `getInt` member. There must be quite a few questions here on stackoverflow.com alone about how to see if a structure or class have a specific member function, if you just search a little.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/DZyv-Q

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: @rafix07 it worked!. My question is how does constexpr help. isn't the template code generated at compile time? why only is_same itself is not enough?

Comment: @Sumit `constexpr if` is different from a regular if and was introduced in c++17. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if .

Comment: The constexpr if is needed because otherwise the compiler will evaluate the condition at compile-time, and only include `v.getInt()` if the condition is true. If you don't have a constexpr if then the compiler will try to build the `v.getInt()` call even if `v` doesn't have any `getInt` member function, which will lead to a build error.

Comment: I just discovered that I can't use c++17

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be able to call a function `f` for all types that have function member `getInt`, not just `X`, you can declare 2 overloads for function `f`:

1. for types that have `getInt` member function, including class `X`
2. for all the other types, including class `Y`.

**C++11 / C++17 solution**

Having that in mind, you could do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_getInt : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_getInt<T, std::void_t<decltype(((T*)nullptr)->getInt())>> : std::is_convertible<decltype(((T*)nullptr)->getInt()), int>
{};

class X {
public:
    int getInt(){
        return 9;
    }
};

class Y {};

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<!has_getInt<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void f(T& v) {
    // only for Y
    std::cout << "Y" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<has_getInt<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void f(T& v){
    // only for X
    int i = v.getInt();
    std::cout << "X" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    X x;
    f(x);

    Y y;
    f(y);
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJIDspLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIABykADqgWE6rR6hiZmln4BanR2Ds5Gbh7eSirRtAwEzMQEIcamForKmKpBGVkEsU6u7l6Kmdm5YQUK9RX2VQk1ngCUiqgGxMgcAORSAMz2yIZYANTiYzrqLcSYzEbz2OIADACC45PTmHMLBACePpgA%2BgTEzIQKG9t7uwSYRj7Cr8c6Zxe0a5hSDNfloAccACIzABuqDw6Eeu2WBlUMwQzAUl2AmAIAEl6DMQDMWugQCAqGwlNdzkdxOZZOZwfNZLsnq93p8aSdqf8jEcACoInZIlFojFY3H0eY6PlA4mkmFw65SrBTEFQCB8gBU3VoBlYrB8N26AFoNuK8QQIN1uo8xtgCUSCCSQHgMWhaFD3GoXOxlcVWGqoFqdXqDUbTXbzfQrb0ZvYCILafTGWNmc8dlN0QoZgANOZ0p4%2BAw%2BvDIEBPGaVuP4qOWm0F3ZVpszFYEAa0GYATiZFartMZLIZPZZu0zCmzAE188nh%2Bm2R9mF8pSCefzSL3m1WV2C5SBQT6rngqFKwGBRZjsRapQK7fK2AZATMb9hSSDNRCZrr9YbiIKFegZioDUpAANmhbppw3GYAHpoJmOhWFOQCSBmCcoN3NADAIb4pTmSRJDQ/CcIWR1nWsVhZ37J5WTeBcly5P4wRlKDN23XlSNJfd2EuI8pXPWtrw2O9DEfZ9X2pd95khL8w1/O0nn/QDgMkMCoXrNMm1g%2BDaEQ5DiFzKD4zjD8oQAOlrK1ZybDD%2BmwqVcKkSQc0c4idA4vdtAo1NqKHEcdiMow7loK1IMbKs8wADysqsgIim1vL8psp1OaLKyA054rTfthl6VgQGGABWYZSFMYYtmK1B8p0OQ5CJfpBhpSQxk4YqCHy8rrVIABrEBuE7UzPAKvruBAsYxi2HhJE4EChHy7hitK8rSEq4ZioUEAtlINqypy0g4FgGBEBQVB3jwdgyAoCA0FO86QGATtJFIKgzteYh1ogFx2uKlx7CyU58pa0hrt5egAHkdP%2BnbSCwQLRHYL7obwFYSk9daocwCLiiwkYlvjZQEdYPAXFuYhTj0LAAda4g8CMSnehoegmDYDgeH4MwhBEMQapkIQifWyBelQQ0gjR41iSkiQZDkThzDWooSg0CBrEaUxOCsbRKniRJBEiQI6BVnX/D12hNeqDw1ZSYo0jKBp9DyQRLYV9JWlNzpzbqcoDYtl32i1mpOF6BR6qGLhcvyoqSoRlaIs8EDjRA7gZmAZBkC7UzJBmCBcEIFDxjVmY9Bu9w8LGSQIOqqWZFar7Op6gqtlMnh64KsYQJAztBvMTxuAK2bhnm0hafryOoZWtaNq2mu9sOiAkFsosCHIShrp8M6akezB8CId2GcYFh4dZgB3W4fDpvuI8Wir8vGDPD8IBAZhjuOE6TlO08kauds6hBViwDwrT7gPIem1L7LXyuPTa20Oq9Drg3JuWwW5tw7gVLuPc%2B5jAWlHcBk8v5h2GB/EeS0x44OgaQT0b0gi9SAA).

Please note that [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) is introduced in C++17, but if you are limited to C++11, then it is really easy to implement `void_t` on your own:

```cpp
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

And here is C++11 version [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJM6kt6ADJ5amAHLGARpmIgArKQAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTpbeycjV3cAZkVlTFVAhgJmYgJg41NzZJVI2gysgmjHFzdPRUzs3NCLBTryu0q46oSASkVUA2JkDgByKQS7ZEMsAGpxBJ11ZuJMZiNZ7HEABgBBUfHJzBm5ggBPb0wAfQJiZkIFNc2d7YJMI29hZ8OdE7PaFcwAOkB922Bn8oimADdUHh0JdDgARSHQ9CzWTbB7PV7vA6zL6nLR/UhTb4Eow4hKIqEw4FbRYGVRTBDMBTnYCYAgASXoUxAU2a6BAICobCUl3xMwA7LIJfDUQ8MS83swPriSb8yVMACo0ukMpkstmc%2Bi4zVEqmwgi4rATElQCCagBUXVoBlYrG8Vy6AFo1oauQQIF0uvcEtgeXyCAKQHgWWhaBC3GpnOwralWLaoI7na73Z6faG/fRAz0pnZLaH5VLxDK5ejthNmQopgANSVorbeAzJvDIEAPKYD0vcwsB4NV7aDydTJYEfq0KYATlrW0n1dl6JrCXbDwbCibAE022vlwqscryXifn8taR%2B1PJ2rr/zBQTkxc8FRcWAwPrWez/SaayChCbAGJgRLaqGgokg6CJTC6boesQNLmlMVD2lIABskJdEeE6DgA9ARUx0KwxxoSQUz7neA7PigfQEJ8uIzJIkjUaxTFzBGUZWKwJ41nWWyYkqKpHPi6oHKaNH3sS4lPpGL6/G%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%2Bh5IIpupMUAetDEXshy0rtNC0nsdN7PQKGNgxcK17Wdd1ZPXQV62YV6mHcFMwDIMgi7/JIUwQLghCUaMFhTHoQNuCxCSSLhQ2GzIM0Iwty0eBs/w8EPHgJJhmELptErrdwXhtUMZ2kMLQ85wT123fdj3969H0QEgDGdgQ5CUID3g/dU4OYPgRDexDdCMCwpPSwA7tc3giydHXnbn7WjNXV%2BhAEBTHzoXYupdy6V0kH3Z6C0EDLCwO4QM39l6rwehdfq7Ut4PSevNHog9h6jw2OPSe08PCz3nt/BIv8N7YJ3nAzOQwYHr0upvBh%2BDSAJhhubbgQA).

**What do we have in C++20?**

C++20 brings lots of good things and one of them is [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). Above thing that's valid for C++11/C++14/C++17 can be significantly reduced in C++20:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept HasGetInt = requires (T& v) { { v.getInt() } -> std::convertible_to<int>; };

class X {
public:
    int getInt(){
        return 9;
    }
};

class Y {};

template <typename T>
void f(T& v) {
    // only for Y
    std::cout << "Y" << std::endl;
}

template <HasGetInt T>
void f(T& v){
    // only for X
    int i = v.getInt();
    std::cout << "X" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    X x;
    f(x);

    Y y;
    f(y);
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:85,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:85,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:85,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:85,startLineNumber:5),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+HasGetInt+%3D+requires+(T%26+v)+%7B+%7B+v.getInt()+%7D+-%3E+std::convertible_to%3Cint%3E%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+X+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++int+getInt()%7B%0A++++++++return+9%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Y+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+f(T%26+v)+%7B%0A++++//+only+for+Y%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Y%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3CHasGetInt+T%3E%0Avoid+f(T%26+v)%7B%0A++++//+only+for+X%0A++++int+i+%3D+v.getInt()%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22X%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++X+x%3B%0A++++f(x)%3B%0A%0A++++Y+y%3B%0A++++f(y)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Comment: Prior to C++17, that implementation of `void_t` causes issues to some old compiler though (as pointed by the link).

Comment: it is not strictly necessary to write two overloads (replacing "need" with "can" would be much better imho)

Comment: I want to ask something different, how is second function template selected for f(y). Aren't both template functions suit f(y) ?

Comment: I think Concepts is singular (as in "one of them is Concepts" or "Concepts is a new feature")

Comment: The concept definition is not accurate. you are assigning the result to an int so the concept should be `template<typename T>
concept HasGetInt = requires (T& v) {
    {v.getInt()} -> std::convertible_to<int>;
}; `

Comment: @Hui yes, you are correct. That would more correct. I missed that point so I will update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You might use `if constexpr` from C++17:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& v){
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, X>) { // Or better create trait has_getInt
        int i = v.getInt();// I want this to be called for X only
    }
    // ...
}
```

Before, you will have to use overloads and SFINAE or tag dispatching.

Comment: `if constexpr` is a C++17 feature.

Comment: @NutCracker: Not nice to update tag/question and so invalidating existing answers... (even if warning about that is fine).

Comment: i just updated tag... question title was updated by OP

Answer (score 7):

Keep it simple and overload. Has worked since at least C++98...

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& v)
{
    // do whatever
}

void f(X& v)
{
    int result = v.getInt();
}
```

This is enough if there only ever one type with `getInt` function. If there's more, it's not so simple anymore. There are several ways to do it, here's one:

```
struct PriorityA { };
struct PriorityB : PriorityA { };

template<typename T>
void f_impl(T& t, PriorityA)
{
    // generic version
}

// use expression SFINAE (-> decltype part)
// to enable/disable this overload
template<typename T>
auto f_impl(T& t, PriorityB) -> decltype(t.getInt(), void())
{
    t.getInt();
}

template<typename T>
void f(T& t)
{
    f_impl(t, PriorityB{ } ); // this will select PriorityB overload if it exists in overload set
                              // otherwise PriorityB gets sliced to PriorityA and calls generic version
}
```

[Live example with diagnostic output.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68b1ea3aea5b0778)

Comment: In this case this would work since there is only one overload (for `X`), but, if there were more of similar types with member `getInt` in the future, this is not such a good practice. You probably want to note that

Comment: @NutCracker Did so.