# Detect if a specific C++ type has a member, EXCLUDING inherited members

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, detection, type-traits

I would like to detect if a particular type has a member: directly and *not as a result of inheritance*.

The purpose is to determine if a *specific* type 'has a trait' such as the ability to serialize. Naturally, and for extending the example, a sub-type might not have the ability to serialize even if the parent type does.

- Is there (and if so) a "standard" solution to this request?
- Is there a flaw (excluding the limitations it imposes) with the non-convertible pointer approach presented at the bottom?

When using `is_member_function_pointer` or other detection mechanisms, inheritance is in play. Note that the output is "1" even though B does not define the member.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
   void member() { }
};

struct B : A {
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "B has member? "
              << std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&B::member)>::value
              << std::endl; 
}
```

The closest I have been able to achieve is when using a non-convertible pointer (`B**` has no implicit conversion to `A**`), although such is a bit awkward to work with. It also imposes the additional argument matched to the type and prevents any direct inheritance.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    // would match std::declval<B*> as B* -> A*,
    // hence forcing failure through B** -> A**.
    // void member(A*) { }
    void member(A**) { }
};

struct B : A {
    // succeeds compilation aka "found" if not commented
    // void member(B**) { }
};

int main()
{
    // This actually fails to compile, which is OKAY because it
    // WORKS when used with SFINAE during the actual detection.
    // This is just a simple example to run.
    //   error: invalid conversion from 'B**' to 'A**'
    std::cout << "B has member? "
              << std::is_member_function_pointer<
                decltype(std::declval<B>().member(std::declval<B**>()))
              >::value
              << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute function inside function template only for those types that have the function defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112341/execute-function-inside-function-template-only-for-those-types-that-have-the-fun)

Comment: Instead of trying to detect the presence of a member, you could require the thing passed to the function specialize some type trait you create for you library and then you can check the result of the type trait.

Comment: @NutCracker No, it doesn't - unless the details are buried. That answer/question does not deal with *inheritance*, which is where this issue is arising.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's done too for the 'unobtrusive form' :) I'm hoping to get a similar effect for the 'obtrusive/inline' form.

Comment: If you compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could write some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for your needs (provide some new GCC builtin doing what you want)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Unfortunately there are several less common compilers that must be supported (can mandate full C++14 support though).

Comment: And if you use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) you could extend it too

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So now I just need to write, install, and maintain plugin for Clang, GCC, IIC, NVCC, etc ;-)

Comment: You could decide to choose to use mostly GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a neat trick that can help with that.

The type of `&B::member` is actually `void (A::*)()`, not `void (B::*)()` (if `member` is inherited).

Use SFINAE to check that `&B::member` exists *and* has a proper type:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_member : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> struct has_member
    <T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<void (T::*)(), decltype(&T::member)>>>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

This only works for one specific member type (`member` has to be `void member()`). Generalizing it for any type is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

Or you can get fancy and use the fact that `void (B::*)()` is for some reason not implicitly convertible to `void (A::*)()` specifically when passing a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, T>
struct detect_member_helper {};

template <typename T>
using detect_member = detect_member_helper<void (T::*)(), &T::member>;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool has_member = std::experimental::is_detected_v<detect_member, T>;
```

Comment: It doesn't really work. Check [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Vyh-Lr) example

Comment: @NutCracker That's because it expects a different signature of `member`: https://godbolt.org/z/MG5C_S

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wow, that.. works! I couldn't figure out how to work in `is_same_v` yesterday. It was also very hand to note "the type of &B::member is actually void (A::*)()". A few small shims and works in Clang 3.9.1 (yeah, old, it's one of our .. baseline .. targets).

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void member(A**)
    {}
};

struct B : A
{};

template <typename, typename = void>
struct hasMember : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct hasMember<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T*>()->member())>>
    : std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T*>()->member()), void>
{};

int main() {
    std::cout << "B has member ? "
              << hasMember<B>::value
              << std::endl; 
}
```

And the output is going to be `B has member ? 0`.

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:10),source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%0A++++void+member(A**)%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B+:+A%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename,+typename+%3D+void%3E%0Astruct+hasMember+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+hasMember%3CT,+std::void_t%3Cdecltype(std::declval%3CT*%3E()-%3Emember())%3E%3E%0A++++:+std::is_same%3Cdecltype(std::declval%3CT*%3E()-%3Emember()),+void%3E%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22B+has+member+%3F+%22%0A++++++++++++++%3C%3C+hasMember%3CB%3E::value%0A++++++++++++++%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: [Pro Tip] `((T*)nullptr)` can be replaced with `std::declval<T*>()`

Comment: Thanks. That's effectively how the code in the original code is being used (the SFINAE/detector was eliminated for example). However, it still relies on the non-convertible pointer / non-overridden method to function. It's workable here.. just hoping it might be possible to elicit without needing such.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that `&B::member` is `void (A::*)()`, you might do

```
template <typename C, typename Sig>
struct classMember : std::false_type{};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
struct classMember<C, Ret (C::*)(Ts...)> : std::true_type{};
// and other specialization for cv and ref and c ellipsis

template <typename, typename = void>
struct hasMember : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct hasMember<T, std::enable_if_t<classMember<T, decltype(&T::member)>::value>> : std::true_type
{};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HSPGVh)