# Detect if a function/operator/method having certain signature is defined

Tags: c++, sfinae

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112341/execute-function-inside-function-template-only-for-those-types-that-have-the-fun) question, how can we detect (at compile time) if a function/operator/method having certain signature is defined?

From linked question and looking at cppreference about [std::void_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) we can write (C++17 ahead)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

class X { public: int someFunc() const{ return 9; } };
class Y{};

template<typename, typename = std::void_t<>> struct Has_someFunc
    : std::false_type{};
template<typename T> struct Has_someFunc<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().someFunc())>>
    : std::true_type{};

template<typename T>
void f(const T& v){
    if constexpr(Has_someFunc<T>::value)
        std::cout << "has someFunc()\n";
    else
        std::cout << "has NOT someFunc()\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "X "; f(X{});
    std::cout << "Y "; f(Y{});

    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
X has someFunc()
Y has NOT someFunc()
```

but what if we want to test a type to have `someFunc` not only to be defined but also having a certain signature?

Though I'm using C++17 also answers in any other version of the standard are welcome.

Comment: Do you want to know if a `someFunc()` is invocable with a given signature (this is simple, starting from your code) or if exist a `someFunc()` with exactly a given signature? In second case: what about if there is a template `someFunc()` that is compatible with the given signature?

Comment: For my current need is enough your first statement, i.e. if I can call the method using arguments which are convertible from the ones I have and then get back a result which is convertible to the type I need.
But I would like also to know how to be more strict about types.

Comment: Added an answer for the first case: a simple modification of your code. If you want to be more strict (check an exact signature)... maybe you should explain better what do you exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend check if a type has a method `someFunc()` that is **compatible** (in-vocable with) a given signature) and return a given type, you can modify your code as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

class X
 { public: int someFunc (int, long) const { return 9; } };

class Y
 { };

template <typename, typename = void>
struct Has_someFunc : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T, typename RType, typename ... Args>
struct Has_someFunc<std::tuple<T, RType, Args...>, std::enable_if_t<
   std::is_same_v<RType, 
      decltype(std::declval<T>().someFunc(std::declval<Args>()...))>>>
    : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename RType, typename ... Args, typename T>
void f (T const & v)
 {
   if constexpr (Has_someFunc<std::tuple<T, RType, Args...>>::value)
      std::cout << "has someFunc()\n";
   else
      std::cout << "has NOT someFunc()\n";
 }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "X "; f<int>(X{});
    std::cout << "X "; f<int, int, long>(X{});
    std::cout << "X "; f<int, int, int>(X{});
    std::cout << "Y "; f<int>(Y{});
}
```

Drawback: you get "has someFunc()" also from third invocation because the last argument (a `int`) is compatible with the last expected argument (a `long`).